# In electron relative paths not working in html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I am not able to set path of CSS and other file in my app's login screen.

my project folder structure.

[image]

Error i am getting

[image]

project's main file

[image]

I have added bootstrap and jquery using

```
npm install <packagename> --save
```

I have experience in web development using PHP but I am very new in electron development.

Comment: The error image shows the full path to your CSS file and you can see it is looking for the file relative to the folder where the html file is located. This is the exactly how relative links should behave. If you want to access something which is in the parent folder, use `../` in the relative link.

Comment: @KishorV Thanks for the response but i have tried like ../ this also but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using path like ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a:

```
<base href="/index.html" />
```

in the index.html page, which made the normally relative links absolute-